Pandas operations between non-float types and NaN
What are the reasons behind pandas allowing operations between sets / strings / other non-float types and NaN (yielding NaN), whereas pure Python does not?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.Series([np.nan]) - pd.Series([{5}]) # yields a NaN-series
pd.Series([np.nan]) - set([5]) # throws error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'set'"


Please don't post pictures of stack traces.

NaNs have a specific meaning in a pandas Series. They should remain NaNs on most operations. Series operation thus provide this as a convenience for some types.
For example with strings:
pd.Series([np.nan, 'a', 'b']) + 'c'

0    NaN
1     ac
2     bc
dtype: object

This is most likely handled since string operations are quite common. Set operation are just not handled from scratch (they are in absence of NaNs: pd.Series([{4, 5}, {5}]) - set([5])), maybe because they are iterables which is a particular type of data and always tricky to build a Series. Anyway, you should keep in mind that string/set/python operations are not really performed vectorially by pandas.
One possibility would be to drop the NaNs, perform the set operation, then restore the NaNs:
s = pd.Series([np.nan, {4, 5}, {5}])
s.dropna().sub({5}).reindex_like(s)

0    NaN
1    {4}
2     {}
dtype: object

Alternatively, with a custom function:
s.map(lambda x: x if pd.isna(x) else x-{5})

0    NaN
1    {4}
2     {}
dtype: object


But why does Python not yield NaN as well? What is the reason for not allowing the operation and returning NaN?

Because python sets are not designed to operate with NaNs, This is actually the same with strings: np.nan + 'c'. Pandas makes this possible as a convenience.
